# MATLAB Surface Plotting

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, 3d, geometry-surface

I want to plot the region (of integration) in 3d-space given by the conditions `-1<=x<=1, 0<=y<=1, 0<=z<=1-x^2` with translucent single-coloured faces in essentially 'wireframe'.

My solution basically draws the four bounding surfaces of the region separately. I used `surf()` for the bottom face that lies on the x-y plane and the top face; however `surf()` doesn't seem to work with the two vertical faces. Hence I guess that there has to be an easier way to draw this...

Cludgiest code ever:

```
figure
hold on
x = linspace(-1,1,30);
y = linspace(0,1,30);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
Z = 1-X.^2;
h = surf(X,Y,Z);
set(h,'edgecolor','none','FaceColor','r','FaceAlpha',0.5);
Z = zeros(30);
h = surf(X,Y,Z);
set(h,'edgecolor','none','FaceColor','r','FaceAlpha',0.5);
Y = ones(30);
z = 1-x.^2;
y = x.*0;
h = fill3(x,y,z,'r');
alpha(h,0.5);
y = y+1;
h = fill3(x,y,z,'r');
alpha(h,0.5);

y = linspace(0,1,30);
x = y.*0+1;
z = y.*0
plot3(x,y,z,'k')
```

[image]

Comment: Please add the code to your question, seems you already finished most of the work. I think replacing `surf` with `fill3` solves the issue.

Comment: Looks good to me. The code above now seems to do what is wanted.